# How can I add a key without a value in an object PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to scan through my files and order them based on ".php" and ".html". ( I want them to appear first)

```
    if(isset($_POST["requestFileNames"])){
    $path = '../';
    $files = [];
    $pages = [];
    $handle = @opendir('./' . $path . '/');

    while ($file = @readdir($handle)){
      if("." !== $file && ".." !== $file){
        if (strpos($file, '.php') !== false || strpos($file, '.html') !== false){
          if(!is_dir($path.$file)){
            array_push($pages, $file);
          }
        } else {
          if(!is_dir($path.$file)){
            array_push($files, $file);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    @closedir($handle);
    sort($files);
    unset($handle,$ext,$file,$path);

    echo json_encode($pages);
  }
```

This outputs : 
["hello.php", "index.php"];

$files contains :
["something.txt", "test.txt"];

What I want the output to be : 
["hello.php", "index.php", "something.txt", "test.txt"];

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: much easier to use `glob()` then sort the array

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two arrays using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$combined = array_merge($pages, $files);
echo json_encode($combined);
```

Example of combined array: https://3v4l.org/0vE0F

Comment: This does not produce the output I want, as you can see in my question.

Comment: It will output `["hello.php","index.php","something.txt","test.txt"]`, which appears to be exactly what you put? In the example link, I am using var_dump so you can see how the array is structured. In the example I gave above, it uses json_encode to put it into the required format instead.

Comment: Alright, I didn't pay attention enough, I am sorry. This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you!